# NSURLRequest returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm developing a hybrid application with Cordova 6.0.0, where I have to call a native Objective-C function from the Javascript side. After looking up solutions on SO, I have implemented the connection as follow:

On HTML page:

```
window.location = "nativeCall";
```

On IOS side:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{ 
    NSURL* url = request.URL;

    return [super webView:webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}
```

Javascript to Objective-C connection is successful, since whenever `window.location` is changed, I can debug the breakpoints on above lines.

However, the `request` object always returns nil. I need to parse `request.URL` to catch the string from javascript function. I tried the following:

```
window.location = "#nativeCall"
window.location.hash = "nativeCall"
window.location.hash = "#nativeCall"
```

But it still results with a nil request object on IOS side. Why could `request` be nil?

Comment: If you are using Cordova, then create a plugin, you don't have to change `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` to handle your call to a native class, the plugin will do it for you

Comment: How are you loading the request to the WebView?